# SVD decomposition of $A(B+\lambda I)^{-1}A^T$ given SVD of $AB^{-1}A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices, svd

Let $C=AB^{-1}A^T$, where $B$ is symmetric, positive definite and invertible. Define $C_{\lambda} = A(B+\lambda I)^{-1}A^T$, $\lambda>0$ assume we know the SVD decomposition of $C$ what can be said about the SVD of $C_{\lambda}$?

My dream would be if $\sigma_i$ is a singular value of $C$, then $\sigma_i + \lambda$ is a singular value of $C_{\lambda}$ or something like this, but I don't know how to procede. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Do we know something on matrix $A$? And mind that even if $B$ is invertible, $B + \lambda I$ might not be

Comment: No, $A$ is any matrix. I'm afraid $B+ \lambda I$ is always invertible when $\lambda>0$. But it is not a problem here, we can assume it is invertible too.

Comment: so $B$ is symmetric positive definite.  You should directly state this in your post.  Let's suppose $A$ is invertible, then your question is what does the eigendecomposition of $\big(A^{-^T}(B)A^{-1}\big)$ look like relative to that of $\big(A^{-^T}(B)A^{-1}\big) + \lambda A^{-T}A^{-1}$ for arbitrary $\lambda \gt 0$ and arbitrary $A\in GL_n\big(\mathbb R\big)$.  I think the best you can do is interlacing for the eigenvalues which won't say much anything about the eigenvectors.